# How to add custom checkout fields and save them in db?

Tags: magento2, checkout

I need to add some fields to the shipping address form from checkout page, and then save them in database.
Please tell me how to do this thing?

Comment: Which magento version ?

Comment: magento 2 version

Comment: @all, please check this link, solution is here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

Answer (score 4):

A quick example shows how to add a custom field in checkout page and save it into database.

First of all, because the necessary information of quote table will be transferred to sales order, so we should create our new custom field `custom_test` in `quote` and `sales_order` tables:

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * Upgrades DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $quoteAddressTable = 'quote';
        $orderTable = 'sales_order';

        //Quote address table
        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($quoteAddressTable),
                'custom_test',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' =>'Custom Test'
                ]
            );
        //Order address table
        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($orderTable),
                'custom_test',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' =>'Custom Test'

                ]
            );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Add our custom field to checkout page **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!--Our custom test fieldset here-->
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="customer_test" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">300</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create `fieldset.xml`

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/fieldset.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
    <scope id="global">
        <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote">
            <field name="custom_test">
                <aspect name="to_order" />
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </scope>
</config>
```

Basically, this fieldset is used for defining the attribute which will be copied from quote object to order object automatically.

Don't forget to create `registration.php` and `etc/module.xml`

**app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

Run setup upgrade command: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`. Now, we can see our new custom field in checkout page and database `quote` and `sales_order`.

After that, now we can create more functions to work with quote and order objects.

Comment: After I installed your module, the custom  field show up in tables quote_address and sales_order_address, but it not appear in frontend shipping address form.

Comment: I made some changes to this module and now I can see the custom field in frontend but I can't save it in db.
I checked for errors in var directory and all is well.Please help me!

Comment: I will check! How you fixed the custom field on the frontend?

Comment: I think the problem appears when I click the next button, Custom checkout field is not sent in post data request, If you check the console you will see this.
I don't know why this is happening. 
You can check this in the new version of module: https://github.com/rlaa/custom-checkout-fields/blob/master/Vendor_v2.zip

Comment: Hi, may i know how this save to database part work?
I dont see any code which can save to the database in your code.
I've do exactly as you, but ignore the `UpgradeSchema.php` and `fieldset.xml`.
Does that 2 files are everything it need to save to database?

Answer (score 3):

I deleted the view directory  and I added the following files:
**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="vendor_add_custom_field" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface">
        <attribute code="custom_test" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Checkout/Model/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout;


class LayoutProcessor

{
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {



        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['custom_test'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
                'options' => [],
                'id' => 'custom_test'
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_test',
            'label' => 'Custom test',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => [],
            'sortOrder' => 252,
            'id' => 'custom_test'
        ];

        return $jsLayout;
    }

}
```

after that run: php bin/magento setup:upgrade, php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: Hi @rla i have followed the above steps but its values are not saving in sales_order and quote tables

Comment: It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Download module from GitHub and make changes as per requirements.

[Magento2 Checkout Custom Form](https://github.com/sbodak/magento2-checkout-custom-form)