# Magento2 checkout page add custom text field

Tags: magento2, checkout, custom-field

Can anyone helps me how to add a custom text field and value save in database:

I have followed the below link text field is created but the value is not saving in database:
[How to add custom checkout fields and save them in db?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126036/how-to-add-custom-checkout-fields-and-save-them-in-db)

Answer (score 1):

For Custom attribute you needto use layoutprocessor and custom extension attribute.

Here is the good example, you can use it.

https://github.com/dckapblog/Custom-field-in-checkout-page

Comment: Not working in Magento 2.4.*

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial and its worked for me.

> https://webkul.com/blog/add-custom-field-checkout-address-form-magento2/

Comment: is the above field is saving the values in db or not

Comment: hi, field is showing in frontend but in tadabase value is not saving

Comment: @shivashankarm Then please try this too https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126036/how-to-add-custom-checkout-fields-and-save-them-in-db

Comment: i was also tried that link but value is not saving in database

Comment: Did you check that post data request? is your custom field data passing to next step?

Comment: when iam placing the order order is placing but value is not saving

Comment: Ok can you share your module here? i will check.
Zip your file and upload to https://uploadfiles.io/ and share here

Comment: Hi i have uploaded please find the link:https://ufile.io/wklgb