# How to add extra fields in checkout page and save them into sales_order table?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, sales-order

Can someone please explain the correct procedure to add custom fields in checkout page and save it into database in **sales_order** table. I have found various tutorials and blogs but none of them work properly.

I have tried it using observers and all but this process doesn't seem right.

Comment: Try this I Hope to help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126036/how-to-add-custom-checkout-fields-and-save-them-in-db

Comment: Well, that seems incomplete. I found a solution here: https://oyenetwork.com/articles/magento2-devliery-date-module-creation-from-scratch/ which is 100% working. BTW, thank you for the reply

Comment: @ManishJoy, THEN Please Can you Post Your answer so that it can be helpful to other.

Comment: @Learing_Coder Hello, I already did. I have posted the link where I found the proper solution. https://oyenetwork.com/articles/magento2-devliery-date-module-creation-from-scratch/