# Magento 2.2.5: How does Checkout Save data?

Tags: checkout, magento-2.2.5

I am stucking at understand how checkout save the data.

[image]
I saw they use `submit: setShippingInformation`, so i follow this function and i got here:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\model\shipping-save-processor\default.js

And here is what i saw in `default.js`

```
if (!quote.billingAddress()) {
                selectBillingAddressAction(quote.shippingAddress());
            }
```

And i `console.log(quote.shippingAddress());` and saw it render all the data from the `shippingAddress` form.

That is it. I dont know where to go next, the `quote.shippingAddress()` in `quote.js` doesn't show me anything at all.

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\model\quote.js

Here is it (i guess):

```
shippingAddress = ko.observable(null)
```

Please give me advice on how to make the next move. I dont know what to do right now.

Comment: Magento2 store all information in local storage. When you place order then only data will be saved to database.

Comment: So what if i have custom a module that override the checkout page, and i want to save the data to the database?

Comment: What is your custom page do?

Comment: And ofcouse in that custom checkout module, i've create a few more input :)

Comment: What is the work of your custom module?

Comment: in the custom module, i create 3 more input, and i want to add them to database, i've created successfully 3 input and render it out :)

Comment: Can you check this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126036/how-to-add-custom-checkout-fields-and-save-them-in-db

Comment: thanks you very much, but it seem like doesn't have the save to database part .. :)

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @magefms yes i did, i've follow this module and its worked. 
https://github.com/saxsax1995/magento2-module-delivery-date

Comment: Magento will call API to save data by each checkout steps e.g. save payment/ save shipment , not only in local storage