# Adding a new field to one page checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, custom-field

I have a special field (Customer reference no, field id = cus_ref_no) that i need to add to checkout.
it is not related to shipping and billing. I have been following the answer from [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126036/how-to-add-custom-checkout-fields-and-save-them-in-db), but for adding the custom field to checkout page app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
I am not sure how to do this part - since the field is neither part of shipping and billing. It is an independent field that needs to be displayed as the first step on the checkout. How should i proceed to adding this field?

And how can i sort the field so that it is displayed as the first field on the checkout page - since i do not see this in the answer to the previous question?

Comment: You can follow the tutorial here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html

Comment: It's pretty much boiled down to the xml file, you look at the xml structure and insert your component there, so if you are looking for a fully tutorial for your case, there won't be one.